# Pandas, how to count the occurance within grouped dataframe and create new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I get the count of each values within the group using pandas ?

In the below table, I have Group and the Value column, and I want to generate a new column called count, which should contain the total nunmber of occurance of that value within the group.

my **df** dataframe is as follows **(without the count column)**:

```
------------------------- 
| Group| Value | Count? |
------------------------- 
|   A  |    10 |      3 |
|   A  |    20 |      2 |
|   A  |    10 |      3 |
|   A  |    10 |      3 |
|   A  |    20 |      2 |
|   A  |    30 |      1 |
-------------------------  
|   B  |    20 |      3 |
|   B  |    20 |      3 |
|   B  |    20 |      3 |
|   B  |    10 |      1 |
------------------------- 
|   C  |    20 |      2 |
|   C  |    20 |      2 |
|   C  |    10 |      2 |
|   C  |    10 |      2 |
-------------------------
```

I can get the counts using this:

```
df.groupby(['group','value']).value.count()
```

but this is just to view, I am having difficuly putting the results back to the dataframe as new columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `transform`

```
df['count?']=df.groupby(['group','value']).value.transform('count').values
```

Comment: No need for the `.values` I think, not that it hurts.

Comment: @miradulo Yes you are right ,That is just my habits ... :-)

Comment: I don't blame you, I know sometimes when masking it can be a decent speedup.

Comment: @miradulo Man , I mean you were right for sure :-) , I always appreciated those people  who help me improved :-),take it easy

Comment: Thanks a ton ! I read the entire pandas document about agg(), and was doing some weird stuff. But I knew it could be done much simpler.

Power of panda

Comment: @Viki yw~ have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Try a `merge`:

```
df

   Group  Value
0      A     10
1      A     20
2      A     10
3      A     10
4      A     20
5      A     30
6      B     20
7      B     20
8      B     20
9      B     10
10     C     20
11     C     20
12     C     10
13     C     10


g = df.groupby(['Group', 'Value']).Group.count()\
                      .to_frame('Count?').reset_index()

df = df.merge(g)
df

   Group  Value  Count?
0      A     10       3
1      A     10       3
2      A     10       3
3      A     20       2
4      A     20       2
5      A     30       1
6      B     20       3
7      B     20       3
8      B     20       3
9      B     10       1
10     C     20       2
11     C     20       2
12     C     10       2
13     C     10       2
```